# Is [singleton-methods] another instance of [singleton]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There does not seem to be the slightest difference between [singleton-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton-methods) and simply [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton)

[singleton-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton-methods) has only a handful of uses.

---

**NOTE** thanks to duplode, we know that [singleton-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton-type) is an obscure and specific field of study in "type theory" in comp. sci.  It is unrelated to "singletons" in the sense of OO questions about singletons and that tag should not be removed or merged.  It's possible "singleton-type" should be renamed to (say) "DDT-singleton-theory" (or something) to avoid naive shotgun use of the tag, by people searching on "singleton" for everyday questions about singletons.

Comment: By the way.  I'm curious....i only for the first time today bothered to make posts here about obvious tag duplicates (such as this one).  It seems incredible that nobody before, i.e. the 4000 people who have posted "singleton" questions, noticed the lame duplicate tags.  Perhaps I misunderstand something, or I'm just wrong on how it all works.

Comment: This request seems reasonable.  Both of the extra tags have under 100 questions.

Comment: Don't remember when it was first explained to me, but the markdown syntax is just `[tag:tag-name]` or `[meta-tag:meta-tag-name]`

Comment: who knew?  what a [meta-tag:world]

Comment: I guess that wasn't very clear, but only the `tag-name` is variable.  You prefix with either `tag` or `meta-tag` and then follow it with the actual name of the tag, which is usually hyphen delimited on SO.  Then the provide links to the actual tag pages (if they exist).

Comment: thanks again.  you know, I can't make it [tag:work] in a comment .. no big deal of course.  TBC I am seeing only red underlined words in my attempts in comments.  in your comments I see the epic gray box.

Comment: Yeah comments don't support that.  But at least they still are links to the actual page of the tag.

Comment: ah all understood, cheers. thanks again

Comment: So like ... is someone going to merge these or what ?

Comment: Note that [singleton-type] is not about the singleton OO design pattern, and so it shouldn't be merged with [singleton]. [singleton-type] refers to a technique which uses types with a single inhabitant to facilitate dependently typed programming. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16017294/2751851) summarises it well.

Comment: @duplode brilliant I had no idea, thanks

Comment: I have the suspicion that this tag was actually created for singleton methods in [tag:ruby], which have nothing whatsoever to do with the singleton design pattern and that the tag excerpt (which really makes no sense at all) was added later. I would advise against just synonymizing it. Either make it distinct from [tag:singleton] or delete it, but as it stands now, about half of the questions (including the first question, which created the tag) are about singleton methods in Ruby and not at all about the singleton design pattern.

Comment: I suspect the same is true for [tag:singleton-class] as well, by the way. I noticed that the synonymization has already happened, and as a result, a significant portion of questions about [tag:singleton-class]es in Ruby are now wrongly tagged with the [tag:singleton] design pattern.

Comment: "another instance" heh. I see what you did there.

Comment: lol looper - finally someone gets it!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've [suggested these as synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/singleton/synonyms) and you can vote for them.

Comment: seems amazing!  someone should just set it to "4" so you don't have to wait since it's obvious!

Comment: This is a community, not a dictatorship :)

Comment: can we vote to have that changed to save time

Comment: As [I mentioned in a comment to the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306382/merge-singleton-methods-and-singleton-type-in-to-singleton?cb=1#comment249272_306382), [singleton-type] should not be merged with [singleton].

Comment: @duplode: in that case, please [write a wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/83207) for singleton-type.

Comment: @jtbandes Excerpt created, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

> I can see no special meaning in "singleton methods" ... they're all just the usual question about when/how to use singletons on different platforms.

I disagree. About half of the questions (including the [oldest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135995/is-it-possible-to-define-a-ruby-singleton-method-using-a-block), which possibly created the tag) are about singleton methods in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and not at all about the [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) design pattern.

If half the questions are about something else, you surely cannot say that they're "all" about singletons.

I have the suspicion that this tag was actually created for singleton methods in Ruby, which have nothing whatsoever to do with the singleton design pattern. The tag excerpt (which really makes no sense at all) was added much later, almost 5 years during which time the tag was mostly used for the Ruby concept. I would advise against just synonymizing it. Either make [singleton-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton-methods) distinct from [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) (I volunteer to help write a tag excerpt and wiki and retag non-relevant questions) or delete it, but as it stands now, about half of the questions tagged with it would be *wrongly* tagged, if [singleton-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton-methods) were made synonymous with the [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) design pattern tag.

Comment: I suspect the same is true for [tag:singleton-class] as well, by the way. I noticed that the synonymization has already happened, and as a result, a significant portion of questions about [tag:singleton-class]es in Ruby are now wrongly tagged with the [tag:singleton] design pattern.

Comment: fascinating information, **SURELY** the tag(s) in question should include the word "Ruby"

Comment: It seems unfortunate that an obscure little technology like "Ruby" should be able to take over and confuse such basic tags and subtags.  wouldn't it be a better approach, where words of general value in comp sci ("singleton") are at hand, that there's simply a tag "singleton" and then people can add "Ruby" etc as fit?  Tags don't exist in isolation, questions have more than one tag.

Comment: As it stands now, "singleton" is *not* a "basic tag" or a "word of general value in comp sci", it is *specifically* about the *Singleton Software Design Pattern*, which is a very narrow specialized thing. This is an entirely different discussion, then. What you propose is changing the meaning of [tag:singleton] from the *Singleton Software Design Pattern* to the generic English word "singleton". That's a valid approach, of course. What I am objecting to is a simple synonymization of [tag:singleton-methods] to [tag:singleton], because contrary to the claim in the question, half of the questions

Comment: … are *not* about the *Singleton Software Design Pattern*, which, however, is the (current) meaning of [tag:singleton]. I'm definitely not proposing that Ruby should take over nomenclature. The term "singleton method" in Ruby, and the term "Singleton Pattern" in the design patterns community arose independently at around the same time, I believe. The term is not exclusive to Ruby, AFAIK, at least Sapphire and Fancy also have a similar concept, and also call it "singleton method". Whereas I never heard someone refer to a "method related to the singleton pattern" as a "singleton method".